# convert datetimestamp to RSS pubDate

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, rss

I have a publishDate of this format from the DB. "2011-08-30 22:47:38.047"
How do i convert this to the RSS pubDate format for example: 'Wednesday, April 25, 2012 3:00 PM'. In DB the date is in this format:"2011-08-30 22:47:38.047"

Comment: What is the targetted language?

Comment: @Boris Strandjev ...im doing this in .Net Db is SQl server

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of java code that achieve what you want:

```
String input = "2011-08-30 22:47:38.047";

SimpleDateFormat inputFormat =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(input);
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(inputDate));
```

the output from this snippet is:

```
Tuesday, August 30, 2011 10:47 PM
```